# How to merge two Dictionaries including only unique values

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

How should i merge two dictionaries to receive dictionary that consist of values that are changed or uniques values? I try to use dictionary extension but i receive only merged dictionary that is combination of both.

Example of the input and output data is presented below.

Example :

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func mergeOptions<K, V>(dict: [K: V]){
        for (k, v) in dict {
            self.updateValue(v as! Value, forKey: k as! Key)
        }
    }
}
```

Input data:

```
var defaultOptions = ["Content": true, "Authentication": false, "Prefix": "buu", "Database": true]

let updatedOptions = ["Content": true, "Authentication": true, "Prefix": "ua", "Database": false, "CP": true]
```

Preferred output:

```
var output = ["Authentication": true, "Prefix": "ua", "Database": false, "CP": true]
```

Comment: Dictionaries are kept unique by keys, not values.

Comment: Yes i know but i am interested how to receive only unique values or that values that are changed.

Comment: A concrete example of input and expected result might be helpful.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk that result dictionary is not unique by values. You have both keys `Authentication` and `CP` that have the value `true`.

Comment: @Fogmeister sorry for me it is quite hard to explain. But in result i would like to have dictionary that only have values that changed and new values. Values that are same should not be in the new dictionary

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk ah, I see now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    mutating func mergeOptions(dict: [Key: Value]) {
        for (k, v) in dict {
            if self[k] == nil || self[k] != v {
                self[k] = v
            } else if self[k] == v {
                self.removeValueForKey(k)
            }
        }
    }
}

var defaultOptions = ["Content": true, "Authentication": false, "Prefix": "buu", "Database": true]
let updatedOptions = ["Content": true, "Authentication": true, "Prefix": "ua", "Database": false, "CP": true]

defaultOptions.mergeOptions(updatedOptions)
print(defaultOptions) // ["Database": 0, "Prefix": ua, "Authentication": 1, "CP": 1]
```

Note that these dictionaries are of type `[String: NSObject]`, which is why the Booleans are printed as 0 and 1 instead of true and false.

Comment: Note that you also need to `import Foundation` or similar. If not then you'll get this error on your `Dictionary` variables: "error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context". This is due to the values in the dictionaries being different types, when you import Foundation the variables are defined as `Dictionary<String,NSObject>`

Answer (score 1):

As dictionaries simply store a unique key and an associated value, you can just add all values that are not yet part of the dictionary and override all other values where a key already exists in case the value is different; remove the value for the key otherwise (but setting the value for the specified key to `nil`). This can easily be done like the following:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    mutating func mergeOptions(newOptions: [Key: Value]) {
        for (key, value) in newOptions {
            if let selfValue = self[key] where selfValue == value {
                self[key] = nil
            } else {
                self[key] = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that I use the generic parameters of the dictionary itself (and not extra generic parameters for the function), which is necessary and certainly what you want to achieve with Swift's type safety.

Comment: It also removes any keys where the value is the same between the new and old versions.

Comment: Well, yeah, it "updates" these values - wasn't this the question? My algorithm works fine for the provided sample input from the question.

Comment: Yes, except you missed the part that removes any keys where the values are the same between the old and new versions. Look at the example input and output. The output doesn't contain a `Content` key because it is the same between the two dictionaries.

Comment: Ahhh thanks, didn't notice  I think Robert's answer will provide the correct solution then, but I'm going to update mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use reduce (I just wanted to try it out):

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func reduceToUpdatedValuesOnly(newDictionary: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
        return newDictionary.reduce([Key: Value]()) {
            if self[$1.0] == nil || self[$1.0]! != $1.1 {
                var dict = $0
                dict.updateValue($1.1, forKey: $1.0)
                return dict
            }
            return $0
        }
    }
}    

defaultOptions.reduceToUpdatedValuesOnly(updatedOptions)
```

you can also just do (if you just need to do it once or twice):

```
updatedOptions.reduce([Key: Value]()) {
    if defaultOptions[$1.0] == nil || defaultOptions[$1.0]! != $1.1 {
         var dict = $0
         dict.updateValue($1.1, forKey: $1.0)
         return dict
    }
    return $0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
var defaultOptions = ["Content": true, "Authentication": false, "Prefix": "buu", "Database": true]
let updatedOptions = ["Content": true, "Authentication": true, "Prefix": "ua", "Database": false, "CP": true]
defaultOptions.mergeOptions(updatedOptions)

extension Dictionary {
    mutating func mergeOptions(dict: [Key: Value]){
        for (k, v) in dict {
            let value = self[k] as? AnyObject
            if value != nil && value!.isEqual(v as? AnyObject) {
                self.removeValueForKey(k)
            } else {
                self.updateValue(v , forKey: k )
            }
        }
    }
}
```